# Patents and Products

Tags: patent-services, product

I need to know if there is a tool that can tell if a patent returned to a prodcut or a service or software.

Thanks
Jumana

Comment: It’s unclear what you are asking for. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Are you asking if there is an easy way to tell if the inventor ever commercialized an invention represented by a particular patent?

Comment: yes right this is exactly what i meant

Comment: None I’m aware of.

Comment: can I use royalty rate per patent as an indicator for the success of a patent?